# Trouble Including CSS Modules with React Server Rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am trying to render my application server side, and it keeps throwing up on each Sass rule.

Tried adding a server Webpack config:

```
const serverConfig = {
  name: 'server',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    './lib/server/helpers/serverRender'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'serverRender.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'lib/server')
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Here is my server renderer:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
// import App from '../../src/index';

const serverRender = async () => {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div>Loading...</div>);
};

export default serverRender;
```

Here is my server code where I'm rendering this via Express:

```
import serverRender from '../helpers/serverRender';
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  const initialMarkup = await serverRender();
  res.render('../index.ejs', { initialMarkup });
});
```

This appears to work, but the moment I uncomment out the imported App file in my server renderer, it yells about Sass styles.

I've tried including the serverRender.js file in /static/, but can't ever seem to find the module.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: When I rendering just a loading tag, I get:

Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting.

When I try to import App.js, I get 'Unexpected token @import', which makes sense, but not sure where transpiled file is (static, dist)? Not even sure if transpiling correctly